# Publish Platform Events from Salesforce for External Subscriber

Tags: platform-event

I am new to Platform Events . I would like to know what do we need to do from the Salesforce side so that the published event through Trigger can be consumed by external source. Ex : I created a Platform Event and I am publishing it when an Opportunity is created/edited

```java
trigger OppTrigger on Opportunity (after insert , after update) {
    
    List<Deal__e> eventlist = new List<Deal__e>();
    
    for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
        Deal__e e1 = new Deal__e();
        e1.Opp_Id__c = o.Id;
        e1.Opp_Name__c = o.Name;
        eventlist.add(e1);
    }
    
    List<Database.SaveResult> results = EventBus.publish(eventlist);
    // Inspect publishing result for each event
    for (Database.SaveResult sr : results) {
        if (sr.isSuccess()) {
            System.debug('Successfully published event.');
        } else {
            for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                System.debug('Error returned: ' +
                             err.getStatusCode() +
                             ' - ' +
                             err.getMessage());
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Now with the help of debug I can see that this event is getting successfully Published . But what else do I need to do if someone would like to search for this event? What additional information or procedure I need to follow to make this Published event visible to the outside subscriber.

Comment: Publishing from platform and subscribing from external clients via CometD is lightly covered in [Trailhead tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/platform_events_basics/platform_events_subscribe); the docs have more info.

Comment: see [Platform Events Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_cometd.htm)